# fast boot oem unlock does nothing. No output

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, recovery-mode, fastboot, micromax-yu-yuphoria

I tried unlocking the bootloader of my Yuphoria with the following command

```
fastboot -i 0x2a96 oem unlock
```

But this is the output that I'm getting.

> ...
>   OKAY [  0.001s] finished. total time: 0.001s

It does not show any kind of warning that the data on the phone will be erased. ADB and fastboot is detecting the device. Here is the output for `fastboot -i 0x2A96 oem device-info`

> ... 
>   (bootloader)  Device tampered: true
>   (bootloader)   Device unlocked:true
>   (bootloader)  Charger screen enabled: true
>   (bootloader)  Display panel:
>    OKAY [  0.005s] finished. total time: 0.005s

I tried flashing the recovery.img after that but it does not work. What am I doing wrong? I work on Linux (Ubuntu 15.04)

Edit:
Here is the [link](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_lettuce) to the CM page where I got the instruction from. I followed all the steps mentioned on the page.

Comment: "*after that but it does not work*" -- what does not work? Is there an  error during flashing or can't you boot into your expected recovery or what? What command did you use to flash recovery? What is your source of instructions and from where did you download your recovery.img?

Comment: There is no error. It doesn't boot to the custom recovery after I run the last command. I followed the instructions from CyanogenMod wiki page for the device.

Comment: What is the last command? At least link the instructions and tell us whether you cherry-picked and executed them or did a thorough step-by-step execution? There simply isn't enough information to solve your question.

Comment: I have updated the the question with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I tried flashing the recover using the command:

```
fastboot -i 0x2A96 flash recovery twrp.img
```

That didn't work. So instead I booted directly into the recovery mode using:

`fastboot -i 0x2A96 boot twrp.img`

Once I was in the recovery mode I was able to flash the ROM normally.